# Error when a function with BlobTrigger gets invoked on Beta 0.5.0

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I'm getting the following error

A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll
Additional information: Blob identifiers must be in the format container/blob.

```
public static void ProcessBlob([BlobTrigger("images/{name}")] string input)
{
Console.Write(input);
}
```

even if i have nothing in the images container

the error went away when i cleared the azure-jobs-host-output and azure-jobs-host-archive folders then came back when i uploaded the job to azure webjobs, any idea?

I downloaded the updated github solution and having the same issue whenever BlobTrigger function gets invoked, queuestrigger is working alright though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the error that you are reporting but I cannot.

I have a few questions that hopefully will help us find the root cause:

1. Does the error happen when you upload a particular blob? If yes, what's the name of that blob
2. Are you using the samples from GitHub as they are or did you modify them (except adding the connection string)?
3. What are the steps that you do to get that error? Do you run the samples or invoke from dashoard?
4. Does it happen only when you deploy in a web site or it also happens locally?
5. Do you get the exception when the host starts or when the function gets invoked?
6. Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: Another question would be when you used 0.5.0-beta were you using the Microsoft Azure storage account which had logs from 0.4.0-beta?

Comment: I only started exploring with webjobs 2 days ago, then upgraded to 0.5 saturday morning, so yes, logs from 0.4.0 r still in the storage $logs folder, but for troubleshooting, I've deleted azure-jobs-host-output, azure-webjobs-hosts, input, output, persons containers, but didn't help

Comment: Victor, thanks for the prompt reply
1) It Error when uploading any blob, I’m creating blobs from Azure storage explorer inside the output folder.   
2) I’m using the samples straight  from github (only modified the connection strings) before that as I had the same issue when I was creating my own project .
3) now as I’m running the sample projects again, it’s not crashing anymore but I’m the following output error.

Comment: The thread 0xd44 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll         
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll        
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll      
The thread 0x1124 has exited with code 259 (0x103).    
The thread 0x4fc has exited with code 259 (0x103).    
The thread 0x3d8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).    
... and goes on

Comment: 4) I was using my own project, it happened locally and when deploying to azure, both scenarios, i’m using azure storage (not local storage emulator). 

5) 15 minutes while writing this comment and the sample project, just now the project crashed project on VS  ( Blob identifiers must be in the format container/blob) 

System.FormatException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Blob identifiers must be in the format container/blob.

6) the call stack is empty, not sure where stacktrace is.

Comment: Below is the terminal window output:
`code`
Found the following functions:
BlobOperations.Functions.BlobToBlob
BlobOperations.Functions.BlobTrigger
BlobOperations.Functions.BlobNameFromQueueMessage
BlobOperations.Functions.BlobToQueue
BlobOperations.Functions.BlobIBinder
BlobOperations.Functions.BlobCancelWrite
BlobOperations.Functions.FailAlways
BlobOperations.Functions.PoisonErrorHandler
Job host started

Comment: Executing: 'Functions.BlobCancelWrite' because New queue message detected on 'pe
rsons'.
Executing: 'Functions.BlobToBlob' because New blob detected: input/BlobOperation
s.txt
Executing: 'Functions.BlobToBlob' because New blob detected: input/testBloblName

Executing: 'Functions.BlobTrigger' because New blob detected: output/ShouldNotBe
Created.txt
Executing: 'Functions.BlobTrigger' because New blob detected: output/BlobOperati
ons.txt

Comment: Moustafa, two more questions: 1. Can you try create a new storage account? I'm curious if it has to do with some stale data in the old one. 2. Do you run with first chance exceptions enabled in VS? Does you function actually show up as failed in the dashboard?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. At first it works, but after some time it starts crashing. Sometime later it starts working again. Here's the error from BlobOperations.exe: http://pastebin.com/8ZQkL4GU I'm using the latest version of azure-webjobs-sdk-samples-master.

Comment: Moustafa and Frank, I believe we have identified the issue. It is an edge case bug in the Azure Logs parser. We are going to provide a fix soon.

Comment: Deleting all containers in the storage account does not help. Nor does deleting all Queues. Deleting the storage account and connecting to a newly created one does make the error go away.

Comment: I started using the 0.6.0-beta version of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs on the day of the release, and have not seen this error again, so it indeed has been fixed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a fix is now included in 0.6. however, I ended up using a webservice for the job i was looking to run. will look again into web-jobs if needed